# How to access a property declared in the viewmodel in a class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, ivalueconverter

What I did I created a calendar and my codes are in the `view model` and to be able to highlight the dates I created a class inherited the `IValueConverter`. Now the error is that when i change the month in my emulator and say the current date it the 20th, even though it's a different month the date is highlighted. When I change the month there is a `property` that gets updated in my `view model`. So how can I get access to this `property` in my `converter class`.

Here are my codes:

Complete converter class:

```
public class DateColorConvertor : IValueConverter
{

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object();
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        string dt = value.ToString();
        if (dt == (DateTime.Now.Day).ToString())
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Complete view model:

```
public class calendarViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    DateTime calendarDate;
    public calendarViewModel()
    {
        calendarDate = DateTime.Today;
        Initialize_Calendar(calendarDate);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _DATECollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> DateCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _DATECollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _DATECollection = value;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Event> _eventCollection = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
    public ObservableCollection<Event> EventCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _eventCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _eventCollection = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="CalendarMonthYear" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string CalendarMonthYearPropertyName = "CalendarMonthYear";

    private string _calendarMonthYear ;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the CalendarMonthYear property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string CalendarMonthYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _calendarMonthYear;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_calendarMonthYear == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _calendarMonthYear = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(CalendarMonthYearPropertyName);
        }
    }

    //button next month
    private RelayCommand _nextMonth;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the NextMonth.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand NextMonth
    {
        get
        {
            return _nextMonth
                ?? (_nextMonth = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    calendarDate = calendarDate.AddMonths(1);
                    Initialize_Calendar(calendarDate);
                }));
        }
    }

    //Button previous month
    private RelayCommand _previousMonth;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the PreviousMonth.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand PreviousMonth
    {
        get
        {
            return _previousMonth
                ?? (_previousMonth = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    calendarDate = calendarDate.AddMonths(-1);
                    Initialize_Calendar(calendarDate);
                }));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="DATE" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string DATEPropertyName = "DATE";

    private string _date;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the DATE property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public string DATE
    {
        get
        {
            return _date;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_date == value)
            {
                return;                    
            }
            _date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(DATEPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public void Initialize_Calendar(DateTime date)
    {
        CalendarMonthYear = date.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
        date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
        int dayOfWeek = (int)date.DayOfWeek + 1;
        int daysOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
        int i = 1;
        DateCollection.Clear();
        for (int d = 1; d <= daysOfMonth; d++ )
        {
            if (i >= dayOfWeek && i < (daysOfMonth + dayOfWeek))
            {
                DATE = (i - dayOfWeek + 1).ToString();
                DateCollection.Add(DATE);
            }
            else
            {
                DATE = "";
                DateCollection.Add(DATE);
                if (DATE == "")
                {
                    daysOfMonth++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _dateClick;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the DateClick.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand DateClick
    {
        get
        {
            return _dateClick
                ?? (_dateClick = new RelayCommand(
                async() =>
                {
                    EventCollection.Clear();
                    List<Event> E = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Event>().ToListAsync();
                        foreach(Event evnt in E)
                        {
                            if (evnt.Date.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today.Date))
                            {
                                EventCollection.Add(new Event
                                    {
                                        Id = evnt.Id,
                                        EventName = evnt.EventName,
                                        Desc = evnt.Desc,
                                        Category = evnt.Category,
                                        Location = evnt.Location,
                                        StartingTime = evnt.StartingTime,
                                        Date = evnt.Date     
                                    });
                            }

                        }
                   if(EventCollection.Count == 0 )
                            {
                                MessageDialog m = new MessageDialog("Empty", "No Events today!.");
                                await m.ShowAsync();
                            }
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do  you need to access the highlightedDate object in Converter, instead you will have to check for the "Date" property value on Month change. You must either notify the Date on month change or set it manually.

Comment: Can you help me more on how to notify Date on month change or set it manually. i can figure it out or i am getting it wrong.As i still see the problem that how to not highlight the date on the next month

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the whole problem but if you need to access two Properties on you Converter then you need to use multi-binding.

Why is the date saved in String why not convert it in DateTime?

Best regards Burim Hajrizaj